# Save values of html elements in cookies or something

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that toggles my background, how would i be able to save the opacity of the background so you dont have to push the button to disable/enable it every time you load the a new page/refresh the page.

```
<div id="bg" style="transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;" class="bg"></div>
<button class="bg-toggle" id="test-button">
    </button>

    <button class="bg-toggle" style="background-color: red; left: 95%;" id="test-button2">
    </button>
</body>

<script>
    const bg = document.querySelector('#bg');

    console.log(bg.style);
    bg.style.opacity = '100%';

    const testBtn = document.querySelector('#test-button');
    const testBtn2 = document.querySelector('#test-button2')

    console.log(testBtn.style);

    testBtn2.style.opacity = '0';
    
    testBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        bg.style.opacity = '0%';
        testBtn.style.opacity = '0%';
        testBtn.style.top = '-10000%';
        testBtn2.style.opacity = '100%';
        testBtn2.style.top = '92%';
    });

    testBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        bg.style.opacity = '100%';
        testBtn.style.opacity = '100%';
        testBtn.style.top = '92%';
        testBtn2.style.top = '-10000%';
        testBtn2.style.opacity = '0';
    });
</script>
```

I have no idea where to start

Comment: You could use the [sessionStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage?retiredLocale=de) to save it sessionvise or in [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=de) if you want to have it after a reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LocalStorage API can be used to store and retrive the opacity of the background and i have removed the unwanted css rules

Use the code in your local system because, here you wont't run due to some restrictions.

[DOC HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```js
const bg = document.querySelector("#bg");
const testBtn = document.querySelector("#test-button");
const testBtn2 = document.querySelector("#test-button2");
const opacity = localStorage.getItem("opacity");
console.log(opacity);
if (opacity) {
  bg.style.opacity = opacity;
  testBtn.style.opacity = opacity;
  testBtn2.style.opacity = opacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

testBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("opacity", 0);
  bg.style.opacity = 0;
  testBtn.style.opacity = 0;
  testBtn2.style.opacity = 1;
});

testBtn2.addEventListener("click", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("opacity", 1);
  bg.style.opacity = 1;
  testBtn.style.opacity = 1;
  testBtn2.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

```css
.bg {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bg" style="transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out" class="bg"></div>
<button class="bg-toggle" id="test-button">test 1</button>
<button class="bg-toggle" id="test-button2">test 2</button>
```

Comment: there is 1 problem with this. When reloading the website with bg.opacity = '0', testBtn2 wont be visible, and neither will testBtn, although pressing where testBtn would be does nothing to the background (going from opacity 0 to opacity 0) and making testBtn 2 visible, after that everything works fine

Comment: doing localstorage.clear doesnt do anything. Im also using chrom browser latest.

Comment: Use localStorage.clear() to clear all values or else try in incognito window

Comment: This works, for the opacity. The problem is that top is still equal to -10000%, and the reason why its needed is because if it wasnt testBtn would be invisible, but still on top of testBtn2. If there was a way to change top on top of opacity in
```if (opacity) {
    bg.style.opacity = opacity;
    testBtn.style.opacity = opacity;
    testBtn2.style.opacity = opacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }```
then that would probs work

Comment: why i removed the the top css rule because, it only work with position: fixed,relative,absolute, but the button seems like doesn't have position css rule. You can inspect the dev tool! to check

Comment: it does have position: absolute, dunno in styles.css why it doesnt work. It's ok thought i can just change the color of the testBtn, then, then set type: hidden to true, and delete the opacity for testBtn and it all works, thanks for the persistant help thought :)

Comment: Welcome to so @Wolfboy248

Comment: dont have 15 reputation lmao, although it was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

first retrive background opacity value from localStorage by getItem mehod. Then, If the value exists, set as the opacity of the background. when user click button to toggle background, set the new opacity value into localStorage. I hope it is useful for you:)

```js
const testBtn2 = document.querySelector('#test-button2');
const testBtn = document.querySelector('#test-button');
const bg = document.querySelector('#bg');


// Retrieve the opacity value from localStorage, if it exists
const savedOpacity = localStorage.getItem('bg-opacity');
if (savedOpacity !== null) {
  bg.style.opacity = savedOpacity;
}

testBtn2.style.opacity = '0';

testBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bg.style.opacity = '0';
  testBtn.style.opacity = '0';
  testBtn.style.top = '-10000%';
  testBtn2.style.opacity = '1';
  testBtn2.style.top = '92%';

  // Save the opacity value to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('bg-opacity', bg.style.opacity);
});

testBtn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  bg.style.opacity = '1';
  testBtn.style.opacity = '1';
  testBtn.style.top = '92%';
  testBtn2.style.top = '-10000%';
  testBtn2.style.opacity = '0';

  // Save the opacity value to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('bg-opacity', bg.style.opacity);
});
```